# Add different paragraphs block on translated nodes

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Is it possible to add additional paragraph blocks on an translated node?

If yes; How? I've tried messing around with configuration; but cannot get it to work as expected.

If not; How do we go around this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

That is an open issue. At the moment you can only translate the fields inside of paragraphs, not the outside structure of the paragraphs.

See this issue:

[[META] Support translatable paragraph entity reference revision field](https://www.drupal.org/node/2461695)